# How to build constant current circuit?

Tags: led, constant-current, led-driver

I am an amateur grower of Capsicum Cayenne Chilli and have been experimenting for some years with good results using Compact Fluorescent Lamps in a small indoor grow room, but I am now looking to experiment with the new LED technology.

The supplier of the LED’s tells me that in order to run these units I need to build a ‘current sink circuit’ that will run the LED’s slightly lower than their maximum rating, suggesting that I should ask the good people of the Electrical Engineering forum for advice.

As a sculptor with a good grounding in mechanical engineering I am practically minded so shouldn’t find the physical build a problem [soldering small components for example] but I know precious little about Electrical circuitry, circuit diagrams and components: in this regard I am a complete novice.

That being said I am always keen to learn a new skill.

**My question then is**:

How do I build a Constant Current Circuit in order to run a bank of 40 x 3 W LED’s [these will be in two separate strips of 20 LED] and what components do I need to purchase? [I am based in the UK]

Any help or advice, links to videos etc would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Will the 20 LED's in each strip be electrically in series? Also, do you know the approximate forward voltage and target current you want to use? Also, do you want to power them from house mains? Or do you have a source of DC available already?

Comment: If you tell me your chilli growing secrets I'll help you more. I'm having some success with ghost chillies (early days) but I've noticed the rate of growth has fallen off badly with the short days creeping up. Hit my page and email me if you want dude. I realize this method is the same that cannabis plant growers use but those days are well gone for me!!

Comment: Hi All, many thanks for your comments and suggestions :-) [i'm still getting used to the forum layout so hopefully this is the right way to reply!] As i understand it from the LED supplier, each 20 x LED strip is wired in series, and then the two strips wired in parrallel. Voltage: how would i find the forward voltage please? Target current: the supplier says to run them well within the maximum power to prevent excessive heat build up and unit longevity. And yes i will be using 240v mains supply.

Answer (score 4):

A general analogue answer would be use an op-amp and power transistor like this: -

[image]

There are plenty of other ways though: -

[image]

But if you need a bit more power you could go to a PWM solution: -

[image]

But you don't have to build one. This is an AC in LED out type module: -

[image]

Use your google fu!

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for the circuit diagrams & suggestion of a commercial unit. Unfortunately my problem is trying to remember the basic physics we had at school [some forty years ago!] to fully understanding circuit diagrams :-( i'd really like to be able to build my own unit(s) at some point and so will attempt to brush up on circuit iconography.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are looking to expand your areas of expertise to include circuit design, I'd go with Andy aka's last suggestion: get a commercial unit. Google on "LED power supply". Find a UK supplier, and select a CC (constant current) supply. Assuming about 3.5 volts per LED, a 20-LED string will require about 70 volts, and about 3 x 20 or 60 watts. Get dimmable supplies, and you can adjust the current level to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Hi WRB, as with Andy aka, you're proably be right regarding using a commercial unit for now to get me going. As indicated above my circuitry skills are basic to say the least [i can just about work out a switch from a resistor but not much else!] i'll do as you say and search online for a suitable unit and let you know what i find on offer here in the UK. Thanks for also suggesting a dimmable unit which would be most useful. Am i right in thinking, from the diagram above, that i'm looking for a unit that incorporates a dimmer, or that it can be 'dimmed' ? i'll pm you regarding Chillies!